# EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) App Crashes...Black Screen SOMETIMES

Tags: iphone, ios, crash-reports

I have an iphone app that allows users to scan bar codes and fetch data from my database and save records in their device.

For most the app works great.. but many are now complaining that when they get 200+ records the app shows a black screen and they cannot use the app. I could not replicate until recently.. last week I added 200 records and it did not crash. Several days later I went to open the app and got the black screen. I stopped the app from running in the background- but it still shows black screen.

Now I get the black screen for 2-3 seconds then it closes. and there is no way to access the app. It is a bad bug because users then uninstall, reinstall and lose all 200 records they saved locally.

My crash report is below.. but I cant find the culprit.. must be a memory issues as it only happens when users have many,many records saved locally.

Can anyone tell what the problem is based on the crash report below?

```
Incident Identifier: 6564E93A-18F9-42A3-891D-E750A8A2F540
CrashReporter Key:   02d344b902cbad805bb9f94c8ce7ef17a9c75c40
Hardware Model:      iPhone2,1
Process:         Ultimate Coupon Organizer [796]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/27AE5A2E-DBB1-4F85-A38A-CA8C86AF518A/Ultimate Coupon     Organizer.app/Ultimate Coupon Organizer
Identifier:      Ultimate Coupon Organizer
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2012-03-31 07:27:03.567 -0500
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.1 (9B176)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x311a532c __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35edc208 pthread_kill + 48
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35ed5298 abort + 88
3   Ultimate Coupon Organizer       0x00004e44 -[Ultimate_Coupon_OrganizerAppDelegate     persistentStoreCoordinator] (Ultimate_Coupon_OrganizerAppDelegate.m:547)
4   Ultimate Coupon Organizer       0x00004bee -[Ultimate_Coupon_OrganizerAppDelegate managedObjectContext] (Ultimate_Coupon_OrganizerAppDelegate.m:483)
5   Ultimate Coupon Organizer       0x00003dfa -[Ultimate_Coupon_OrganizerAppDelegate CreateIfNeedDefaultFolder] (Ultimate_Coupon_OrganizerAppDelegate.m:314)
6   Ultimate Coupon Organizer       0x00002cf8 -[Ultimate_Coupon_OrganizerAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] (Ultimate_Coupon_OrganizerAppDelegate.m:88)
7   UIKit                           0x31883e4c -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1176
8   UIKit                           0x3187d97e -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 402
9   UIKit                           0x3184bc64 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1004
10  UIKit                           0x3184b708 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 48
11  UIKit                           0x3184b0dc _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5820
12  GraphicsServices                0x3486e224 PurpleEventCallback + 876
13  CoreFoundation                  0x3528051c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 32
14  CoreFoundation                  0x352804be __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 134
15  CoreFoundation                  0x3527f30c __CFRunLoopRun + 1364
16  CoreFoundation                  0x3520249e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
17  CoreFoundation                  0x35202366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
18  UIKit                           0x3187ca0c -[UIApplication _run] + 544
19  UIKit                           0x31879e76 UIApplicationMain + 1074
20  Ultimate Coupon Organizer       0x000029da main (main.m:14)
21  Ultimate Coupon Organizer       0x00002998 start + 32

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x311953a8 kevent + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x37be4ea4 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 708
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x37be4bc2 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 30

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x311a5cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35e97f36 _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35e97cc8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3 name:  WebThread
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31195004 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x311951fa mach_msg + 50
2   CoreFoundation                  0x352803ec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 120
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3527f124 __CFRunLoopRun + 876
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3520249e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294    
5   CoreFoundation                  0x35202366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
6   WebCore                         0x3231c0f0 _ZL12RunWebThreadPv + 396
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35e9d72e _pthread_start + 314
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35e9d5e8 thread_start + 0

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x311a5cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35e97f36 _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35e97cc8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31195004 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x311951fa mach_msg + 50
2   CoreFoundation                  0x352803ec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 120
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3527f124 __CFRunLoopRun + 876
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3520249e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
5   CoreFoundation                  0x35202366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
6   Foundation                      0x33a64bb2 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 302
7   Foundation                      0x33a64a7a -[NSThread main] + 66
8   Foundation                      0x33af858a __NSThread__main__ + 1042
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35e9d72e _pthread_start + 314
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x35e9d5e8 thread_start + 0

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x311a5cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35e97f36 _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35e97cc8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 7 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x311a5570 __select + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x3528463a __CFSocketManager + 726
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35e9d72e _pthread_start + 314
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35e9d5e8 thread_start + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x00000000
r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x3f8d4d98      r6: 0x3eb36f70      r7: 0x2fdfe0cc
r8: 0x3eb4b198    r9: 0x00000000     r10: 0x3eb36f74     r11: 0x3eb426f0
ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x2fdfe0c0      lr: 0x35edc20f      pc: 0x311a532c
  cpsr: 0x000f0010

Binary Images:
0x1000 -    0xb3fff +Ultimate Coupon Organizer armv7  <bc8f21d83f9e32458dcf20f9072f1743>     /var/mobile/Applications/27AE5A2E-DBB1-4F85-A38A-CA8C86AF518A/Ultimate Coupon Organizer.app/Ultimate Coupon Organizer
0x2fe10000 - 0x2fe31fff  dyld armv7  <4a817f3e0def30d5ae2032157d889c1d> /usr/lib/dyld
0x309f3000 - 0x30b3cfff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <b70646b63f1f3b33896dd8cb91b8dab1> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x30b74000 - 0x30bd8fff  MessageUI armv7  <b74d79ea691a35ada276f063b7217a20> /System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI
0x30bd9000 - 0x30c1efff  GeoServices armv7  <a26be2e76e8730ab91a16502aba376be> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x30c1f000 - 0x30c20fff  DataMigration armv7  <d77f0e8f39ee37f5a2ac713a3fd9e693> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x30c21000 - 0x30c2dfff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <36ce86a3dc8c344596c8c325615f374b> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x30e8e000 - 0x3114ffff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <0e94e9a7e7a334649afaccae0f1215a2> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x3116f000 - 0x31193fff  PrintKit armv7  <08509c7bc915358b953de6f5cbef5c56> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x31194000 - 0x311aafff  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7  <7ac5560851ce3cb3981068092074b409> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x311d5000 - 0x311d8fff  ActorKit armv7  <434c756a6b053f4ba3c954cfccddbf59> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ActorKit.framework/ActorKit
0x311de000 - 0x31277fff  EventKit armv7  <d67aa1508ee7306b8e2a45c76ffddff0> /System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EventKit
0x31278000 - 0x312a8fff  ContentIndex armv7  <7a64670bb2ff3ee39ddee1dc1c72f92d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ContentIndex.framework/ContentIndex
0x312cc000 - 0x312ecfff  libxslt.1.dylib armv7  <39348471007e39dab80af68b08390456> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
0x312ed000 - 0x312eefff  libremovefile.dylib armv7  <402f8956975d3b6fb86ab9b31a43242c> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x312f8000 - 0x31307fff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <ca5b10014b473d2eaec5c48d89ee1b54> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x31440000 -     0x31456fff  DictionaryServices armv7  <6ed2e967136f37d4a4b9b318d6c43b83> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x31462000 -     0x314a0fff  IOKit armv7  <fcda71d29d6136dfbd84c1725f4998e5> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x314a1000 -     0x315c6fff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <2ffc6c87b94434288366bd53765ee267> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x315c7000 -     0x315d6fff  OpenGLES armv7  <e80acc691001301e96101bb89d940033> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x315dc000 -     0x31721fff  CoreGraphics armv7  <903545b89a7f311d95100ac7d1d44709> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x31725000 -     0x31768fff  libcommonCrypto.dylib armv7  <95b49daf4cf038b6bea8010bba3a1e26> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x31769000 -     0x31813fff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <bf822cc1a3243ae7b104cf73ca22d352> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x31848000 -     0x31ceafff  UIKit armv7  <d72bcc68e76a3a55a963590cdcffe8cd> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x31ceb000 -     0x31d99fff  Message armv7  <b8221d43401d315fb84398b7aa570fc1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Message.framework/Message
0x31d9a000 -     0x31dd1fff  Security armv7  <eea56f71fde83c2981f9281dc7823725> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x31dd3000 -     0x31dd7fff  IOSurface armv7  <6ae77a40f8e93f28bc466ca93f5675d4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x31dd8000 -     0x31deefff  libmis.dylib armv7  <258bc92be5823b239b4412dd42cb4807> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x31e50000 -     0x31ed6fff  CoreMotion armv7  <6a9355d5a8e238b5b8f193605d509e15> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
0x32042000 -     0x32046fff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <42dbc26828e934acabb4f3b0a35d8250> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x320c6000 -     0x32117fff  CoreText armv7  <5bfac4ee88d03d5b87a1f105abb7756c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x32150000 -     0x32151fff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7  <9fdc27af7350323bbc7d98e14e027907> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x32155000 -     0x32189fff  MIME armv7  <d30292ea8f7e360fa5f5d5b1b62b602d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MIME.framework/MIME
0x32224000 -     0x32233fff  GenerationalStorage armv7  <d84c3fd0e7bd36e78c256f2f4c5a4e91> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/GenerationalStorage
0x32252000 -     0x32256fff  Marco armv7  <8dea3e558fe534ff868fc92e215ce53b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Marco.framework/Marco
0x32273000 -     0x32a31fff  WebCore armv7  <814351ff217e3425a8e532c2e2251f73> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x32a32000 -     0x32a46fff  PersistentConnection armv7  <65682d21486836a3aa3e17b9461e7b3a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x32a4e000 -     0x32a51fff  NetworkStatistics armv7  <7848d8ebad99367cb4f7f4e3fe88e5d6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NetworkStatistics.framework/NetworkStatistics
0x32a86000 -     0x32ae9fff  IMCore armv7  <6e26e99b9b5f3829a8486ffd8c64f0d2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/IMCore
0x32b13000 -     0x32b19fff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <9e45ce468a6f31e5b8263f2c224aa800> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x32b36000 -     0x32b3cfff  MobileIcons armv7  <ed1b46f917903c9b9baaa2be4392dafe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileIcons.framework/MobileIcons
0x32b58000 -     0x32b5bfff  libcompiler_rt.dylib armv7  <b2c05d8601c13be884097192dca4e187> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x32b5c000 -     0x32d02fff  CoreData armv7  <b0215b6d4d143859a2b313ecade095ec> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x32d03000 -     0x32d0cfff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <4a15e845dc6f3a4a980de66c1cc44c42> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x32db9000 -     0x32dc0fff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <0703f561f9a038b6850d6e93bba7e5f4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x32dd1000 -     0x32dd4fff  CaptiveNetwork armv7  <f5cc4b97ce9432da9426f12621453325> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x32e39000 -     0x32e75fff  AppSupport armv7  <311eac85b2a433a884dacba77217b49e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x32e76000 -     0x32e76fff  liblangid.dylib armv7  <644ff4bcfbf337b5b5859e3f0fc0a9a8> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x32e79000 -     0x32e98fff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <0c55744b6f7335eebba4ca2c3d10b43c> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x32e9c000 -     0x32ea3fff  libc++abi.dylib armv7  <bab4dcbfc5943d3fbb637342d35e8045> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x32f7e000 -     0x32f81fff  libsystem_network.dylib armv7  <356cb66612e836968ef24e6e5c3364cc> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x33287000 -     0x332c6fff  QuickLook armv7  <802b1092542a3017a0380632502610d4> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook
0x33340000 -     0x33359fff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <1828cddc5dd93c61afbefb59587d7f8a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x3335f000 -     0x3336afff  AccountSettings armv7  <373e59421d983c93931cfbad87b1ae35> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x33383000 -     0x333cffff  CoreTelephony armv7  <e8eb52ca5fe33c7488a33efd222e7804> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x333d0000 -     0x333dcfff  libCRFSuite.dylib armv7  <bdb2b4d1a78c39c1ba60d791207aed2a> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x333dd000 -     0x33426fff  AddressBook armv7  <b17a2962e9043e0385c3c2c652155f2b> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x33427000 -     0x33453fff  libtidy.A.dylib armv7  <3aacc5b650e037c086a8ff6657d154bf> /usr/lib/libtidy.A.dylib
0x33454000 -     0x33460fff  CoreVideo armv7  <364fa32d513f3c11b50970120545f1a8> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x335a6000 -     0x335f0fff  ManagedConfiguration armv7  <5e0a131bbfec305ea01f9e01f486da63> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x335f1000 -     0x335f5fff  FTClientServices armv7  <21de970d7ebb3e7fb502a0a5451b0806> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTClientServices.framework/FTClientServices
0x33695000 -     0x3369afff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7  <27bb5462450732e380f5a2c170546e93> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x3373b000 -     0x33743fff  ProtocolBuffer armv7  <0e846afacf823d2b8c029cc3010a8253> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x337a6000 -     0x337acfff  liblaunch.dylib armv7  <aa2bcba6fc7a36a191958fef2e995475> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x337ae000 -     0x337d1fff  MobileSync armv7  <e42604c550283f4aa517ae8f108b340f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSync.framework/MobileSync
0x337d2000 -     0x338c3fff  QuartzCore armv7  <a2afbe6483683d05ad51b106f98776e2> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x338c4000 -     0x33915fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <c352af5a742e3c7a8d4d7e5f6f454793> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x33931000 -     0x339e7fff  AVFoundation armv7  <35cb7a0eb1dc3554a777c1cc11cb0415> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x33a54000 -     0x33bd2fff  Foundation armv7  <c40ddb073142315bb4ebb214343d0b7f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x33be6000 -     0x33bfefff  Notes armv7  <724966ed5cd4395cb70f9c996b123f53> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Notes.framework/Notes
0x33c12000 -     0x33c12fff  vecLib armv7  <a2cfe25e77aa36bfb4a30b2d0d2dd465> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x33f38000 -     0x33f95fff  StoreServices armv7  <628fbbc73ed93730962c53bfbfde6794> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices
0x3416a000 -     0x341b2fff  CoreMedia armv7  <eb1f503312be3c93b07b2d0d25177000> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x341c8000 -     0x341ccfff  CertUI armv7  <f503892ef60e36108d28d8f9d6144d2a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CertUI.framework/CertUI
0x341da000 -     0x341e1fff  StoreKit armv7  <1bc0c05f99a8309d90476b42263e3487> /System/Library/Frameworks/StoreKit.framework/StoreKit
0x3475e000 -     0x3476ffff  libxpc.dylib armv7  <ccf25b1e49ce3b2fa58d8c8546755505> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x3483f000 -     0x34868fff  AppleAccount armv7  <2ba44023410231fcb3f72f762ea3ce6e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleAccount.framework/AppleAccount
0x34869000 -     0x34873fff  GraphicsServices armv7  <e21a6e61bdd136b6805a9e3abe2e3d1f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x34874000 -     0x34897fff  Bom armv7  <c3435ecd2e5839f89de51edad0e1bb00> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x34898000 -     0x34898fff  libunwind.dylib armv7  <e0a73a57795f3e1698a52ebe6fc07005> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x348d5000 -     0x3491ffff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <441b42aca07b3da39feab25f8349918f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x34920000 -     0x34927fff  MailServices armv7  <ab2388ce733e38b7a261273a401bbbf1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MailServices.framework/MailServices
0x34b45000 -     0x34b49fff  AggregateDictionary armv7  <3a3a33f3a05538988c6e2bb363dc46a8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x34eba000 -     0x34ec0fff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <e1f06241ef0e3f0aae00f15df572077e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x34ee6000 -     0x34f5ffff  ProofReader armv7  <6db611d8df6530d480f97a40bc519f70> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x34f93000 -     0x34fcffff  iCalendar armv7  <f2836083051132d3aa40ad82d7f73aea> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iCalendar.framework/iCalendar
0x34fdc000 -     0x34fe0fff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <998fccc16cf735dbb62324202995e193> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x351f3000 -     0x3530afff  CoreFoundation armv7  <6d450fe923d7387f8b01845e0edd713d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x3531b000 -     0x3532afff  MobileDeviceLink armv7  <70ac33720f513f0f97ea2279260678ca> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDeviceLink.framework/MobileDeviceLink
0x3532b000 -     0x3532bfff  libkeymgr.dylib armv7  <ebd2dddf55d83cf48a18913968775960> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
0x35333000 -     0x35338fff  ApplePushService armv7  <f424c0340de637c08bbeb4f3bd8c6eaf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x353fa000 -     0x3541ffff  OpenCL armv7  <ec915bfc3f7633dda61b5fc87459119b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OpenCL.framework/OpenCL
0x35420000 -     0x35420fff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <a80aaa9989483ce3a496a061fd1e9e0a> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x35458000 -     0x35495fff  FTServices armv7  <28ed78e01a77388cb4c0f2f6ec33482c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTServices.framework/FTServices
0x35642000 -     0x356c1fff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <bf01f5ed47b033d8bde30d735ff44416> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x356c2000 -     0x3570bfff  libc++.1.dylib armv7  <5b690e5dd5a43a7fb166ade9fe58a7a4> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x3570c000 -     0x35726fff  CoreServicesInternal armv7  <cccdb5638b17398f8082542c1b3c8cf6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreServicesInternal.framework/CoreServicesInternal
0x35736000 -     0x357a6fff  CoreImage armv7  <86ac6f5a267637b6b7f8a831dfc7c64b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x357f3000 -     0x3582efff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <55941c96cf1f3b048e72a148c4496c16> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x35842000 -     0x35846fff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <9a17d07b5a3b38cfafdf16f78c99b572> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x35847000 -     0x35851fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <40e4045fb79e382b8833707746cf28b1> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x35857000 -     0x35904fff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <58d47f064e0232119f4b838ad659f9c1> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x35945000 -     0x35e89fff  FaceCoreLight armv7  <f326d88709683520b251dc53cb847c11> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCoreLight.framework/FaceCoreLight
0x35e8f000 -     0x35f1bfff  libsystem_c.dylib armv7  <f859ce1ad1773f0ba98d7c6e135b7697> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x35f47000 -     0x35f4afff  CoreTime armv7  <a398de5ba1e43a11b7008e9bb5a7f6fe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreTime.framework/CoreTime
0x35ffa000 -     0x3600bfff  DataAccessExpress armv7  <e6144ba265da3bb7b9a263aa1a29b054> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x36038000 -     0x36074fff  IMFoundation armv7  <77bb4365a65b32a49523b03da0340dbc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/Frameworks/IMFoundation.framework/IMFoundation
0x36077000 -     0x360affff  VideoToolbox armv7  <9f25f38d1cd13a1daff99cfde8884410> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x360cd000 -     0x360cdfff  Accelerate armv7  <55b24cf91a8b3532bde6733c96f14c08> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x361a6000 -     0x3624cfff  AddressBookUI armv7  <da424fecc66e3628ab03378ae80b38fc> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x36291000 -     0x36294fff  libmacho.dylib armv7  <e52b77623bd031bc807e77029566c777> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x36362000 -     0x363b0fff  CoreLocation armv7  <44550ebedf23334d85441d9743b74e03> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x36932000 -     0x36933fff  CoreSurface armv7  <7850befd26b630f183ee326aaadd7b34> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x36a8b000 -     0x36a93fff  MobileWiFi armv7  <b76c3e9fb78234c392058250d4620e72> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x36a9b000 -     0x36a9bfff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <eb82984fa36c329387aa518aa5205f3d> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x36a9c000 -     0x36adcfff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <40448706190031f6b0d9636cc11ee81d> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x36b4e000 -     0x36c10fff  Celestial armv7  <2a59586b0ae937c3b25fe526924aa885> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x36d2e000 -     0x36d4bfff  libsystem_info.dylib armv7  <50863bcbf478323e96a8e5b1a83ea6f9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x36e86000 -     0x3706afff  AudioToolbox armv7  <c91e27850452330ea804db6408840fd2> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x3707d000 -     0x37082fff  CrashReporterSupport armv7  <2bb524b3bb3c3eb2932ce13b655b7c7c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x37123000 -     0x37124fff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7  <66e985f3eea03ef08afb7cf4c153f76e> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x37226000 -     0x3722cfff  libnotify.dylib armv7  <9406297de3e43742887890662a87ab53> /usr/lib/system/libnotify.dylib
0x37271000 -     0x37337fff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <90014d1bc583366d85622e43097df416> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x37338000 -     0x3733dfff  libcopyfile.dylib armv7  <52e874396c393ed29099789ce702cfe2> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x3751d000 -     0x37591fff  MediaControlSender armv7  <87315c54b2293ab589950341ff91b45d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaControlSender.framework/MediaControlSender
0x3759e000 -     0x377cbfff  MediaToolbox armv7  <ec9bc89489763c6c93f86c5c490b2d69> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x3780e000 -     0x37852fff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <757226927a873d5492be721908077b48> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x37875000 -     0x37877fff  libCoreVMClient.dylib armv7  <d4d4aa3090c83e87bcb15ed00b93fd5c> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x37892000 -     0x378c7fff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <4464a4e3bb3f32f7abaa35ebf31fda49> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x37910000 -     0x37927fff  WebBookmarks armv7  <bd20a05587783a8e9596eef1d3615ea7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebBookmarks.framework/WebBookmarks
0x37999000 -     0x379aefff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <66f7557fa4b43979b186e00271839fdb> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x379af000 -     0x37a87fff  vImage armv7  <caf3648be2933384b6aa1ae7408ab4f0> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x37a88000 -     0x37a89fff  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7  <9aede8d6579d3430ac39ae5f95cce498> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x37a8a000 -     0x37ae2fff  CoreAudio armv7  <be335e8eb6f93594b028a6ddd503a183> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x37af8000 -     0x37b2dfff  DataAccess armv7  <89fd0c22338b37538cf61803a0bca9e2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccess.framework/DataAccess
0x37b61000 -     0x37b6bfff  libvMisc.dylib armv7  <e8248c797b9b363594bb652ddf7ce16d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x37bd8000 -     0x37beefff  libdispatch.dylib armv7  <9ecfaef4110a3bf9a92d12f0fe8d1d78> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x37c39000 -     0x37d10fff  CFNetwork armv7  <765a472c824830eea91b8f02d12867e4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x37d3d000 -     0x37d3ffff  MobileInstallation armv7  <215d93dbb0f63cbf828f9126eb7b5349> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x37d40000 -     0x37e10fff  WebKit armv7  <6ff2796c2f933050ac6ecdee9fc6a216> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x381b1000 -     0x3836efff  ImageIO armv7  <02e3578171fa3b6a969b244275fd2bab> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x3836f000 -     0x3837cfff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <750a0de73a733019a77144b805d4d2f8> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x38486000 -     0x3848afff  libcache.dylib armv7  <d6a7436ed8dc33d795c9b42baf864882> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x38492000 -     0x384a8fff  EAP8021X armv7  <fffe86a22bc434a6ae84f23bfecef9d6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x384a9000 -     0x38597fff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <2cfefe2ad1d335dd9549562910e7a2e2> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x38598000 -     0x38599fff  libdyld.dylib armv7  <977b0ad6f2f433108b4a0324a57cd2ab> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
```

Comment: enable the NSZombieEnable and MallocStackLogging to get to know more about crash or you can use malloc_history.

Comment: This type of issue will occur whenever you use Core Data in your Application without proper Data Management as answered by borrrden.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Core Data calls might be crossing some thread boundaries.  Core Data objects are NOT thread safe, so using dispatch_async is a big no no unless you no what you are doing.